# Regex: A word having letter "b" preceded by "a" atleast one time

Tags: regex

What could be the regex for such a word containing combinations of a's and b's? 
Examples:

Words that I want to match: `a, aaaa, ab, aba, abaabaaaab...` (where all words have at least *one occurrence of "a" before every "b"* )

Words that I don't want to match: `b, abb, bba, bbaabbba,abba...` (where all the words dont have at least *one occurrence of letter "a" before every letter "b"*)

I tried with `pattern = \b[a]{1,}?[ab]*\b`

It seems to accept all the words that I wanted to match but also the words `abb,abba...`  (Though each b's don't have the *letter "a" preceding it at least one time*)

[For your kind reference](https://regex101.com/r/gvYAIA/3). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\b(?:a+b?)+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yb4m8y/1)

*Details*

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:a+b?)+` - one or more repetitions of one or more `a`s followed with an optional occurrence of `b`
- `\b` - a word boundary.